# Other distances than euclidean distance in knn

Tags: classification, caret, k-nearest-neighbour

Suppose I want to fit a k-nearest-neighbour using `caret` package in `R`:

```
library(caret)
index       <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
iris_train <- iris[ index, ]
iris_test  <- iris[-index, ]

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                       number = 4, 
                       savePred = TRUE, 
                       classProb = TRUE)

iris_knn <- train(Species ~ ., 
                  data = iris_train, 
                  method = "knn", 
                  trControl = fitControl)
```

As far as I understand k-nn, this algorithm defines the class of an observation according to an election: the *k* closest points to the observation are considered the most frequent class is defined as the correct class for the observation.

Many sources I checked say that Euclidean distance is the most commonly used distance, but suppose I need another distance because of reasons. How can I define another distance using `caret`?

For example, suppose I have evidence to say that Manhattan distance is better than Euclidean to my data set. How can I say this to `R` using `caret` package?

Comment: Why do you stick so much to the `caret` package? Do you want to discuss the *use* of alternative measures of distance or is this basically a question about software, *how* to code/program something?

Comment: I stick with caret because I am more familiar with it. I want to discuss the _use_ of alternative measures of distance in this particular software.

Comment: That is not very clear to me what you want. Do you look for a software solution (which would be off-topic) or something else? The caret package links to `knn::class` which explicitly states to be about Euclidean distance. Do you want to hack this somehow? Do you have a statistics question or a programming question? I do not see how your question is about the *use* of alternative measures, instead of *how* to code/program it. What is the statistical question?

Comment: Questions about how to do something in a particular software are off topic here.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an interesting question, as I havent seen KNN be used with a different distance metric than Euclidean.

The method "knn" does not seem to allow choosing other distance metrics, as it applies the `knn()` function from base R. The method "kknn" however performs k-nearest-neighbour as well using the `kknn` library and seems to use the Minkowski distance which should be the Manhattan distance using the parameter `distance=1`.

Here you can find the available models for caret (This is where I found "kknn"):
http://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html